# Stitch differently-sized pages together

Tags: pdfpages, paper-size

I am producing the cover of a journal in LaTeX. I have separate files for the frontcover, backcover and spine. I would like to combine these into a single seamless PDF that has the height of an A5 sheet of paper but width (2*A5width+1cm) (the spine is 1cm wide). I have tried using `pdfpages`, but it adds space around the spine as though it was an A5 sheet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=0.7in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{}% A local style file for this specific journal; I don't think the other packages are relevant.

\geometry{paperwidth={2\paperwidth+1cm}}
\begin{document}

\includepdfmerge[nup=3x1]{backcover,spine,frontcover}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `delta=-0.5in 0in` as in  `\includepdfmerge[nup=3x1,delta=-0.5in 0in]{pgfmanual,pgfmanual,pullquote}` Use appropriate length so as to remove the space. Will this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pdfpages` provides a macro `delta= <x dimen><y dimen>` to adjust the spaces between inserted pages. You can provide a minus value for `<x dimen>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=0.7in]{geometry}

\geometry{paperwidth={2\paperwidth+1cm}}
\begin{document}

% Try these options 
\includepdfmerge[nup=3x1,delta=-0.9in 0in]{pgfmanual,pullquote,pgfmanual}
%\includepdfmerge[nup=3x1,delta=-0.5in 0in]{pgfmanual,pullquote,pgfmanual}
%\includepdfmerge[nup=3x1,delta=-0.9in 0in,noautoscale]{pgfmanual,pullquote,pgfmanual}

\end{document}
```

In addition to this, there is also `noautoscale` if you don't want to fit the pages in to the master page.

With `delta=-0.9in 0in`:

[image]

With `delta=-0.5in 0in`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. In case anyone is interested I used `\includepdfmerge[nup=3x1,delta=-69mm 0cm]{backcover,spine,frontcover}`, where 69=(148-10)/2, since A5 has width 148mm and my spine has width 10mm.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option you could try:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\geometry{margin=0pt,paperwidth=\dimexpr148mm+148mm+1cm,paperheight=210mm}
\usepackage{atbegshi,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{atbegshi,graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}% Remove first page
\resizebox{148mm}{210mm}{B}% Back
\resizebox{1cm}{210mm}{S}% Spine
\resizebox{148mm}{210mm}{F}% Front
\end{document}
```

A fully blank page is set due to the completely filled line as first page, which is removed using `\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}` from [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi).

Of course, you could use `\includegraphics` to replace the Back/Front/Spine.